# twilio outbound voice call from client - not phone

Tags: c#, twilio, twilio-api

The docs say that the **from** can be a phone number OR **client**
https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls

> From: The phone number or client identifier to use as the caller id. If
>   using a phone number, it must be a Twilio number or a Verified
>   outgoing caller id for your account.

however - the c# sdk **doesnt seem to support the from being a Client** - anyway to use a client instead of a phone number? using twilio voice SDK for ios and trying to allow the call receiver to see it as a "missed call" so they can call back.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio evangelist here.

The helper library asks for an `IEndpoint` as the to parameter.  There are a two classes that implement IEndpoint: `PhoneNumber`, `Client`.

```
var to = new Client("Bob");
var from = new PhoneNumber("+15017250604");
var call = CallResource.Create(to,
                               from,
                               url: new Uri("http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml"));
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Devin - I specifically called out the from param. please see the url and the part I quoted - your example uses a phonenumber.. and its talking about the to param.....

Comment: my bad and you are right it does not appear that the C# lib supports this now.  Checking with the team that owns the lib to verify that.

Comment: With Twilio Client - you could push in additional custom params that would just show up on the APNS payload (and also could push from the client back to the programmable voice url) but that all seems to be gone with the voice SDK - I have a support ticket open for that issue.

Comment: OK, confirmed this is a bug in the C# library and have a filed an issue to get it fixed.  Right now I think the only work around would be to make the HTTP request w/o the helper library.

Comment: Thanks for confirming - my support ticket has been assigned to someone who doesn't know what they are talking about. Is there a way to track the ticket you filed?

Comment: drop me an email with the ticket number and I'll check on it.  devin at twilio dot com